# TextBox with Validation. How to update the target property even if the entered text is not valid?

Tags: .net, wpf, mvvm, binding, validationrules

I have a `TextBox` in my View, bound to a Property `MyText` in my ViewModel. I also have a `ValidationRule` for the input.

Here is the `TextBox` in my View:

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyText"
                 UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" 
                 Mode="TwoWay"
                 ValidatesOnNotifyDataErrors="True"
                 ValidatesOnDataErrors="True"
                 NotifyOnValidationError="True">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:FormulaValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

And here is my Validation class:

```
Public Class MyTextValidationRule
    Inherits ValidationRule

    Public Overrides Function Validate(value As Object, cultureInfo As CultureInfo) As ValidationResult

        Dim validationRes = MyParser.ValidateText(value)
        If validationRes Then
            Return ValidationResult.ValidResult
        Else
            Return New ValidationResult(False, "Input is not valid")
        End If
    End Function
End Class
```

**What I want** is that my property `MyText` gets updated, even if the entered Text is not valid, however, like what I have now, the property gets only updated if the text is valid. Is there any way to do it, i.e., update the property, or access the text of my `TextBox`?

Comment: Try ValidationStep property of ValidationRule class https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.validationrule.validationstep?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Controls_ValidationRule_ValidationStep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `ValidationStep` property of a `ValidationRule` to `UpdatedValue` will cause it to be run *after* the source property has been updated:

```
<Binding.ValidationRules>
    <local:FormulaValidationRule ValidationStep="UpdatedValue"  />
</Binding.ValidationRules>
```

The default value is `RawProposedValue` which means that the validation rule is run before the value conversion occurs and the source property is being set.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do if you want to show a visible indicator that the input is wrong but still keep a record of it is to use `ValidatesOnExceptions`, the following article gives a good explanation of it all:
[Data Validation in WPF](http://www.progware.org/Blog/post/Data-Validation-in-WPF.aspx)

It's kind of meant for if there is a conversion error to the backing property, but there is nothing stopping you taking the value in to the field of the ViewModel in the property setter then performing the parsing and throwing an Exception as desired. That way you'll have a copy of the value set but also the UI showing that there is an error.